# Is libxml2 a DOM parser or a Serial Parser?

Tags: c, libxml2

I made a wrapper for some basic things in libxml2, stuff like grabbing element content, stepping into children nodes etc.

My super has just asked me to make sure I'm parsing the XML file serially and not loading the entire DOM into memory.

I'm pretty sure the I'm doing it serially, but I couldn't find any documentation on parsing one way or the other.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libxml2  can operate in either mode.  It just depends how your code uses it.  You can either parse the full file into a DOM, or use Sax callbacks to parse serially.  What does your parsing code look like?

Comment: I ended up using the Sax callbacks so I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different APIs you can use.

xmlTextReader is a streaming reader that you'd want to use, calling xmlTextReaderRead() repleatedly to advance the parser through the file.
http://xmlsoft.org/xmlreader.html

If you're working with xmlDocPtr/xmlNodePtr objects returned by things like xmlParseFile, then that's the tree-based DOM API.
http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#tree1.c